# Clicking a button with Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have a particularly difficult form that I am trying to click the search button and can't seem to do it. Here is the code for the form from the page source:

```
<input type="image" name="" src="http://images.example.com/WOKRS53B4/images/search.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" onclick="return check_form_inputs('UA_GeneralSearch_input_form','search');" title="Search" alt="Search" class="">
```

I am trying to do the standard mechanize click action:

```
login_page = agent.click(homepage.link_with(:text => "Search"))
```

Is this because the button uses javascript? If so, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a link, it is a button. What you need to do is look for the form (for example, with `form_with`) and then look for the ImageButton and `submit` it.

Comment: Do you have some code that demonstrates how to use an image input to submit a form?

Comment: I think you should consider asking a proper question since it doesn't seem related to this one.

Answer (score 39):

I struggled with this too, especially since my form had multiple buttons.

There are multiple ways to submit a form (with many using a 'form_with' block), but this helped me:

```
# get the form
form = agent.page.form_with(:name => "my-form")
# get the button you want from the form
button = form.button_with(:value => "Search")
# submit the form using that button
agent.submit(form, button)
```

See more info [here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html#method-i-buttons_with-28criteria-29)

Also, make sure you upgrade to the latest mechanize. I was using mechanize 1.x, which was giving me "undefined method" errors for the code above.

Comment: thank you. one correction is required in syntax ":value"  to ":values"

Answer (score 0):

```rb
button = form.button_with(value: 'Search')
form.click_button(button)
```